# Cross Site Scripting Array Multiple Results

Tags: xss, code-injection, htmlspecialchars, html-injections

Hello lovely people of StackOverflow,

I built an application to store movies, so i can search for them at a later time. All is working but i'm trying to prevent XSS, I've looked at W3School htmlspecialchars, but the problem i'm running into is that i'm returning multiple fields results such a s"keywords" " category" "Date Saved" "Website".

I can prevent XSS on only one field but then the rest of the fields don't return any data.

Here is the code that echo's the data from the database:

```
    echo "<tr align='center' bgcolor='#0f7ea3'> 
    <td height='25px'>"
    .$results['Website']."</td>
    <td>".$results['Keywords']."</td>
    <td>".$results['Category']."</td> 
    <td>".$results['Date Saved']."</td>
    <td> <a href='" . $results['Website'] . "'>Click To Access Your Link</a></td>
    </tr>" ;
```

Hopefully I've explained my issue correctly.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an update to the suggestion provided by "nobody"

The code provided was accurate except with the "**.**" placement. Other than that, the code worked perfect.

Suggested:

`<td>"htmlspecialchars(.$results['Date Saved'], ENT_QUOTES)."</td>`

Correct Code:

`<td>".htmlspecialchars($results['Date Saved'], ENT_QUOTES)."</td>`

Complete Working Code:

```
 echo "<tr align='center' bgcolor='#0f7ea3'> 
    <td height='25px'>"
    .htmlspecialchars($results['Website'], ENT_QUOTES)."</td>
    <td>".htmlspecialchars($results['Keywords'], ENT_QUOTES)."</td>
    <td>".htmlspecialchars($results['Category'], ENT_QUOTES)."</td> 
    <td>".htmlspecialchars($results['Date Saved'], ENT_QUOTES)."</td>
    <td> <a href='" . htmlspecialchars($results['Website'], ENT_QUOTES) .       "'>Click To Access Your Link</a></td>
    </tr>" ;
```

Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

I think I understand your question but I don't know why you could only escape one result.

You can do:

```
echo "<tr align='center' bgcolor='#0f7ea3'> 
<td height='25px'>"
.htmlspecialchars($results['Website'], ENT_QUOTES)."</td>
<td>".htmlspecialchars($results['Keywords'], ENT_QUOTES)."</td>
<td>".htmlspecialchars($results['Category'], ENT_QUOTES)."</td> 
<td>".htmlspecialchars(.$results['Date Saved'], ENT_QUOTES)."</td>
<td> <a href='" . htmlspecialchars($results['Website'], ENT_QUOTES) . "'>Click To Access Your Link</a></td>
</tr>" ;
```

This prevents XSS by injecting JavaScript into the echo. Also notice that I used the ENT_QUOTES flag in the htmlspecialchars function. This escapes both double and single quotes as they are not escaped by default.

However, your script is still vulnerable if you don't verify the URL that can be injected in the href tag ($results['Website']).

By setting "javascript:alert(123);" as your URL you can still execute JavaScript. You need to verify that the URL starts with http:// or https://.

Comment: Hey there "nobody" i so much appreciate your response i will try this and post back the outcome. Thanks again....

Comment: No problem, glad it worked! I also fixed the typo (thanks for spotting). Can you accept the answer please?